# These credentials do not match our records. laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

hi I'm using Laravel authentication.
in my login form if i submit without filling fields i see an error that says the filed is required . but when i try to fill the form with wrong username and password it has to say "These credentials do not match our records."
but it wont say
I'm using laravel 5.1

```
  @include('errors.error')

        {!! Form::open(['url' =>'/login' , 'method'=>'POST','class'=>'form-signin']) !!}
        <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>

        {!!  Form::text('usr_UserName',null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>' &#xf104;']) !!}
        {!!   Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

this is my form

```
@if($errors->any())

<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <span>
           <li> {{ $error }}</li>
        </span><br>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

@endif

and this is my error page

Comment: What does it say then? Have you checked the error log for any messages?

Comment: By default Laravel auth should return a "Whoops! Those credentials do not match our records" error. Is anything showing in your error logs? Have you overwritten the auth function at all?

Comment: share some of your codes so that we can see how you are trying.

Comment: @TheFallen i count the error variable and its 0 !

Comment: @James error logs is empty and no !

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim what part of my code do u want  to see ?

Comment: @AmirTahani your view and your auth controller